# Django Reverse Relationship property not exists

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, python-3.6, django-1.11

Let's say I have `AssetUser` model looks like follow.

```
class AssetUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

my query set looks like follow.

```
qs = User.objects.get(pk=1)
```

when i run `qs.assetuser_set` i am getting error like follow.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'assetuser_set'

what mistake i made here.

Comment: Is the app that contains this model in INSTALLED_APPS?

Answer (score 2):

Django models should be inherited from Model class, so you need to change your code to this:

```
class AssetUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: i updated the question correctly, still getting same error

Comment: @N.HariHaraSudhan did you run makemigrations/migrate commands? Can you show `User` model? What if you change `User` to `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`? `user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`? Did you try to add `related_name`?